# Stuck wtih file input and validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, file-upload, carrierwave

I`m having troubles using ***carrierwave*** but it is not strictly related to it. 
I have Attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :event_id, :file, :file_cache
  belongs_to :event
  mount_uploader :file, AttachmentUploader
end
```

which belongs to Event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

 ATTACHMENTS_LIMIT=3
 attr_accessible ...
              :attachments_attributes
 ...
 has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

and a nested form like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
<fieldset class="attachment">
  <%= builder.file_field :file %>
  <%= builder.hidden_field :file_cache %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields t("actions.delete"), builder %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

and it seems ok, unless once you get a validation error - then all file_fields are being reset with blank values. But there is a file_cache pointing to my ***carrierwave*** upload path(*uploads/tmp/20121003-1959-2388-3822/Getting_Started.pdf*).

How can i preserve files from being lost when validation error occurs??? Any tip would be greatly appreciated! I`ve smoked up those how-tos from official carrierwave wiki and related posts, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After some investigation, I realize that my "image_path" field and before_validation method weren't necessary. All I had to do was this: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays. I'm not sure what the issue with the OP's code is... looks like it should work to me.

---

Just ran into this same problem. The fact that carrierwave keeps the file stored in a /tmp folder is very helpful. Here's what I did, in a nutshell:

Model:

```
class Image < AR:B
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  attr_writer :image_path

  before_validation :set_image

  def set_image
    self.image = File.open(@image_path) if @image_path && !image.present?
    true
  end
end
```

View (using [slim](http://www.slim-lang.com)):

```
- if f.object.image.present?
  = f.hidden_field :image_path, value: f.object.image.current_path
```

** Note: this exposes, in the raw html, the full path to the file on the production server. If that's a security concern for you, you could encrypt / decrypt the path, or set the value to be the raw image data or something.

Comment: Update: I see what you're trying to do. I just read this: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays ... So I think my image_path variable was unnecessary, whereas you just need the appropriate before_validation logic

Comment: And... looks like my before_validation method isn't necessary either. In fact, your code looks like it should work. Did you ever resolve the issue?

Comment: That article from your post is great, and it really helps!